# Calculate reduction of Jacobian of hyperelliptic curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, jacobians, neron-models, hyperelliptic-curves

Suppose I have a hyperelliptic curve of genus $2$ over $\mathbb Q$. I want to get information about its Jacobian reduction at prime $p$ (especially, in case $p=2$). Also I'm interesting in the group of connected components of the Neron model of the Jacobian.

Is it possible to get such information using some computer algebra system (like Magma, Sage and etc)? I know that there is Sage (and Pari) function [genus2reduction](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/plane_curves/sage/interfaces/genus2reduction.html) (Liu algorithms implementation) that is able to give information about almost all reductions. But it doesn't give enough information about reduction at $p=2$.

So I want to focus on case $p=2$ and I'm looking for other solution.

***UPD*** Gave link at `genus2reduction` and pointed that it is implementation of Liu algorithms. Added after Victor Miller answer.

***UPD2*** Thanks to **Michael Stoll**. There is an [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/171767/10300) for almost all cases. But for some curves his solution still doesn't work. So I'm still looking for something else. For example it is impossible to get information about reduction at $p=2$ for such curves like $y^2 = 16*x^6 + 32*x^5 + 16*x^4 + 32*x^3 + 96*x^2 + 64*x + 16$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant information can be obtained from a regular model of the curve over ${\mathbb Z}_p$. Such a model can be computed by repeatedly blowing up points or components of the special fiber that are singular on the arithmetic surface one obtains from the original curve. More or less detailed examples of this can be found in various places, for example [here](http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/stoll/schrift.html#AG17) or [here](http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/stoll/schrift.html#AG9). The component group can be obtained from the intersection matrix of the resulting special fiber.

There is an implementation of regular models in Magma by Steve Donnelly that can do this computations in many (but not yet all) cases. See the function "RegularModel" and the documentation [here](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/1322#14511).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! It is almost the solution! But you are right there are exceptions in `RegularModel` function. For example in some cases it fails with error: `Can't blow up fibre (failed to find an affine transformation to a line)`. So if you know some other way to deal with group of components it wold be great!

Comment: I've updated the question and added examples that produce such error. Please look at them.

Comment: My version of Magma (V2.20-5) computes regular models at 2 for the examples you mention. If you don't have the latest version of Magma and you think you've found a bug, it's usually a good idea to first try the [online-calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/).

Comment: @jsm, thanks. You are right. I've updated the example. It is interesting because there are two curves: $y^2 = f(x) = x^6 + 2*x^5 + x^4 + 2*x^3 + 6*x^2 + 4*x + 1$ and $y^2 = 16*f(x)$. In first case Magma will work as expected, but in second case -- there is error that I mentioned above.

Comment: The curves $y^2 = f(x)$ and $y^2 = 16f(x)$ are isomorphic over $\mathbb{Q}$, so a regular model for one is isomorphic to a regular model for the other and vice versa. In any case, you should let the Magma group know about this.

Comment: By the way, if your curve is hyperelliptic, then you can first call pMinimalWeierstrassModel to make sure that RegularModel starts with an equation that is minimal at 2. This won't affect the information you're interested in, but makes it much less likely that Magma can't compute a regular model.

Comment: @jsm, do you know, is it true that Magma's function calculate reduction and Neron model over algebraic closure of F_p?

Comment: Magma doesn't compute the Neron model, only its group of components. You're right `ComponentGroup` only gives you the geometric component group. But Magma can also compute
equations for the components using the intrinsic `Components` (which does not show up in the
handbook). Then you can use the results of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9804069) by Bosch and Liu to find the $\mathbb{F}_p$-rational points of the component group using the $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}/\mathbb{F}_p)$-action on the components (Magma won't do it for you, though).

Comment: For instance, if all the components happen to be defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$, then $\Phi(\mathbb{F}_p) =\Phi(\overline{\mathbb{F}_p})$, where $\Phi$ is the component group.

Comment: @jsm, if one use Liu algorithm (for defining stable reduction) directly it gives the Neron model possibly after extension of the base field. For me it isn't clear if the implemented algorithm gives the Neron model after extension of the base field or it gives the irreducible components over algebraic extension but for the Neron model of the given base field?

Answer (score 3):

There is a discussion of exactly this here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sage-nt/uBIWZtX1Yas .

Qing Liu has the algorithms implemented as a sage package.  See his home page http://www.math.u-bordeaux1.fr/~qliu/ for more information.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Implementation of Liu algorithms in Sage is `genus2reduction` function that I mentioned above. It works great at any $p \ne 2 $. And it cannot give an answer at $p=2$. Citation from google group discussion: `This still leaves p=2 completely 
out of the picture, however`. So, I still need an answer...