# Computing Tamagawa numbers for jacobians of hyperelliptic curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, computer-algebra, jacobians, magma, hyperelliptic-curves

Do exist some computational approach to calculation of Tamagawa number for the jacobian of hyperelliptic curve at prime $p$?

As followed from this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/172166/understanding-of-tamagawa-numbers-of-hyperelliptic-curve) one can compute $\Phi(\overline{\mathbb F}_p)$ using `genus2reduction` Sage function and in case it is trivial one can assert that $\Phi({\mathbb F}_p)$ is trivial too, so $c_p = 1$. If I understand things right same situation with Magma `RegularModel` approach (see question above and [another question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/171708/calculate-reduction-of-jacobian-of-hyperelliptic-curve)), except note that Magma's approach works with $p=2$, but Sage's doesn't.

So question is how to calculate tamagawa number for jacobian of hyperelliptic curve in general case (or at least in some cases) using some computer algebra system like Sage, Magma and etc?